# Which is better to trigger relayouts in JavaScript - clientLeft hack or requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sometimes, when styles are applied via JavaScript, these changes are not visible because they occur within one animation frame.

---

**Example:**

```
$('.foo').style('color', 'red');
$('.foo').style('color', 'blue');
```

*(Please keep in mind that this example is just for demo purposes in this question and not a real-world example.)*

---

In the example above, color will be immediately changed to blue while red is never visible. Some people use setTimeout to work around this:

```
$('.foo').style('color', 'red');

setTimeout(function () {
  $('.foo').style('color', 'blue');
}, 1);
```

Since this is not a good practice, I wondered which is better to force the change in style to be drawn in the next frame?

---

**Option 1: clientLeft hack**

Requesting the clientLeft value of a DOM element will cause a relayout in the browser.

```
$('.foo').style('color', 'red');
var bar = $('.foo')[0].clientLeft; // hack to force relayout
$('.foo').style('color', 'blue');
```

- Pro: "Just works" across browsers
- Con: It's a hack

---

**Option 2: requestAnimationFrame**

```
$('.foo').style('color', 'red');

requestAnimationFrame(function () {
  $('.foo').style('color', 'blue');
});
```

- Pro: No hack
- Con: [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=requestAnimationFrame) (No IE version lower than 9?)

Comment: I guess its in the contradictions of how you want to use it. If you want it to be a response then left click it is else go with the other. Condition by condition usage of links changes.

Comment: According to MDN IE10 supports requestAnimationFrame - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Browser_compatibility, and Microsoft's website says the same thing (note the IE10 badge) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh773174(v=vs.85).aspx. Also, regarding the original question, why in the world would you `hack` this using `clientLeft` when the desired behaviour is available and built-in to the browser using `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: Finally, if Microsoft no longer supports IE9 (unless you're running Vista, which apparently microsoft no longer supports, so I guess that means they don't support IE9), I think it's safe for you to no longer support it as well. Matter of fact, they don't support IE10 either. We're not back in the IE6/7 dark ages anymore, it's ok to modernize a bit.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for pointing out about IE. I changed that in my question. Regarding your hack question: It also works on older IE versions while raf does not. The decision which browsers should be supported is not in my hands.

Comment: I love it when people just downvote without giving a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that both solutions were not perfect because requestAnimationFrame is not supported on IE9 (and older) and the clientLeft hack is.. well it's a hack.

So, I used [Paul Irish's polyfill for requestAnimationFrame](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) and now I have the best of both worlds:

- I can replace most of my `setTimeout()` calls with `requestAnimationFrame()`
- Newer browsers that support it provide `requestAnimationFrame` natively
- Older browsers get the polyfill

Perfect solution for me.

Comment: IE >= 10 supports requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: @Adam You're right, thanks for pointing out. I'll change that in my post.